# Scope Variable Not Being Set Outside of Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am attempting to create an AngularJS directive that sends a file name, from an `<input type="file">` element, to a file upload factory.  The work is based off the following blog post:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/05/a-file-input-directive-for-angularjs.aspx

I have my HTML element defined:

```
<div file-input="file" on-change="readFile()"></div>
```

With the associated directive set up:

```
myApp.directive('fileInput', function ($parse)
{
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<input type='file' />",
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileInput);
            var onChange = $parse(attrs.onChange);

            element.bind('change', function () {
                model.assign(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                console.log(element[0].files[0]);  // correctly references selected file
                scope.$apply();
                console.log(model(scope));  // correctly references selected file
                onChange(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When I select a file from the element the `change` event is fired and both my `console.log` calls print out a reference to the file that I selected.  But attempting to print out `$scope.file` in my controller does not reflect the file selection:

```
$scope.file = "nothing";

$scope.readFile = function()
{
    $scope.progress = 0;

    console.log($scope.file);  // print "nothing"

    fileReaderFactory.readAsDataUrl($scope.file, $scope)
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.imageSrc = result;
        });
};
```

What am I missing that does not allow the controller to properly set and retain the value sent from the directive?

**UPDATE**

I've made the following updates, but my scope variable is still not being updated.  My change function is called, but it doesn't notice any new value given to `myModel`.

HTML:

```
<file-input my-model="fileRef" my-change="readFile()"></file-input>
```

Directive (`input` tag updated to `text` for testing purposes):

```
myApp.directive('fileInput', function ($parse)
{
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        template: "<input type='text' />",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            myModel: "=",
            myChange: "&"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.myChange();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
$scope.fileRef = "nothing";

$scope.readFile = function()
{
    $scope.progress = 0;

    console.log($scope.fileRef);  // prints "nothing"

    fileReaderFactory.readAsDataUrl($scope.fileRef, $scope)
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.imageSrc = result;
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your directive object add `scope: {file-input: '='}` to have two way binding between your directive's scope and it's parent scope.

Comment: When I do this my `on-change` function is no longer called.  Adding an `onChange: "="` to the `scope` object causes the function to call several times in a row when the page loads, and still does not reflect the updated `file-input` param when I do finally select a file.

Comment: Right, that's not really how directive two-way binding works though. You would need an on-change attribute inside your element that points to the function in order for that to work. Why not just put your unchange function, attribute, etc.. in an object and data-bind to that object.

Comment: I've made some updates to my question, if they spark a thought.  I'm not totally clear on what you're wanting me to data-bind my object to; can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

try adding file to the link function.  I had the same issue and that's what fixed it for me.

As near as I can tell the link acts as the controller (scope) for the template.

However, the one thing that confuses me is that when I added a property to $scope from within a $scope method in the controller the new property is seen by the template.  When added outside the $scope method (still in the controller) it is not.